# I'm trying to convert a SQL query to linq, but I'm getting stuck on combining group by and max()

Tags: sql, linq

What I'm trying to do is find the last ID key column for each SerialNumber column within a table.

Here's the sample tables, truncated to just the columns I need to answer this question.

```
Devices Table
SerialNumber
12345
45678
67890

History Table
ID | SerialNumber
1  | 12345
2  | 45678
3  | 67890
4  | 12345
5  | 67890
```

My expected output would be:

```
ID | SerialNumber
2  | 45678
4  | 12345
5  | 67890
```

Here's the SQL I'm trying to convert from:

```
SELECT max(ID) as ID, SerialNumber
FROM History
WHERE SerialNumber in
 (SELECT Distinct SerialNumber
 FROM Devices
 WHERE DeviceType = 0)
GROUP BY SerialNumber)
```

Here's the best working linq query I've got:

```
var query= from ListOfIDs in History
           where (from distinctSerialNubers in Devices
           where distinctSerialNubers.DeviceType == 0
           select distinctSerialNubers.SerialNumber).Contains(ListOfIDs.SerialNumber)
           select new {ListOfIDs.ID, ListOfIDs.SerialNumber};
```

Using .Max() will return the last ID in the History table.  Trying to group ListOfIDs by ListOfIDs.SerialNumber will separate all ids by SerialNumber, but I can't seem to find a way to get into the groups to run .Max().

Edit:
Thank you for the answers.  This combination of the two answers works well for me.

```
var query= from historyEntry in History
where (from s in Devices where s.DeviceType==0 select s.SerialNumber).Contains(historyEntry.SerialNumber)
group historyEntry by historyEntry.SerialNumber into historyGroup
select historyGroup.Max(entry => entry.ID);
```

Thank you both, I've been trying to figure this one out all day.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you switch from EF to a micro ORM like PetaPoco(http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) or Massive, or Dapper?  Then your knowledge of SQL would not need to transfer over to LINQ.  I love LINQ, but if you're proficient at SQL, there's no reason to not use it.

Comment: Adn what are you planning to do with that id? If you are using it to determine the next id to insert, you are creating (or already have) a process that is subject to race conditions.

Comment: I'm using it to check the latest status for each device within a table. It is part of a left outer join between two+ tables that were split up to create some almost Normal Form Databases. I only posted what I needed to get my question answered, both for the query and the Table data. I've already checked, and it works perfectly.  I must admit, I really wasn't expecting such quick responces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't compiled/tested it but this should be what you're looking for:

```
from historyEntry in db.History
join device in db.Devices on history.SerialNumber equals device.SerialNumber
where device.DeviceType == 0
group historyEntry by historyEntry.SerialNumber into historyGroup
select new { ID = historyGroup.Max(entry => entry.ID), SerialNumber = historyGroup.Key }
```

Comment: Yep.  That seems to work.  All it seems I needed was the [groupName].Max(a => a.id) rather than sticking it outside of the query.  So that's how I can get to things like the SQL Select.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
var snoQuery = (from s in Devices where s.DeviceType==0 select s.SerialNumber).Distinct();

var query (
   from h in History 
   where snoQuery.Contains(h.SerialNumber)
   group h by h.SerialNumber into results
   select new { Id = results.Max(r=>r.id) , SerialNumber = results.Key}
);
```